# MS Search Server Express Throws an Exception

Tags: search-server

I installed MS Search Server Express and crawl some Ektron documents and those documents are successfully indexed.
Next when I tried to search  I got the following error.
[image]

I also installed some hot-fixes as suggested by several websites. However, this error still throws, when I try to search my documents.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen and ended up going to the search manager site - something like yourhost:1234 or some other port.  Once there, you navigate to the search service configuration screen and you'll notice the database connections, etc at the bottom.  An Ektron support person had me create a new configuration and delete the old one.  This actually drops the tables in SQLServer and creates new tables with long numbers at the end of the table names.  After doing this, it all started working again.  You can always drop your Sharepoint* tables, register your site again and do a full crawl to start over.